# wxWidgets compiling with an error

Tags: windows-xp, widget, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile and create wxWidget apps but when its just about done I have a virtual memory runout and there is an error in the wxWidgets code I have tried it several times with 2.8.10 AND 2.8.11, no luck, I am using codeblocks 10.5 and mingw I think version 5.02 but I am not positive whenever I start a wxwidgets app in codeblocks and I compile (no changes made)
there is an error in the buffer.h file I looked practily everywere but couldn't find anything... any help would be greatly appreciated tonight I will try again and post the errors and once more any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

I also tried wxPack which also had an error in the buffer.h file

oh and I am using windows xp professional with the third service pack

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile wxWidgets in order to use these tools. This is not the most Windows-friendly task. You should try [wxDev-C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/), it already comes with MinGW and wxWidgets pre-compiled.

Comment: I also tried dev c++ with the devpak but still came with an error